# How to hide Android sdkmanager download progress bar?

Tags: android, jenkins, android-sdk-tools, android-build, android-sdk-manager

When I run an `sdkmanager` command like `sdkmanager "build-tools;26.0.1"` it spits out hundreds of lines in Jenkins console because of the download progress bar. Is there a way to hide it or put it in quiet mode?

I don't see an option in `sdkmanager --help` output. I'm considering piping the output to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 12):

I ended up hiding the progress bar with grep.

```
sdkmanager --update | grep -v = || true
```

Comment: You saved my life, mate. :)

Comment: I much prefer this solution over the `/dev/null` pipelining, as with only hiding the progress bar, we get error messages and further information while running the SDK manager.

Comment: But Google should really add `--silent` options to their SDK tools

Answer (score 3):

As of now the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager) lists all the arguments and there is no `--silent`. Pipeing it to `/dev/null` to silence it can be a solution.